# Excel formula help needed highligh based on data validation list in cell

Tags: excel-formula

I have many columns with different Data Validation lists so clients can select the correct options.

Each is column specific and doesn't link to another column or cell.

These lists are typed into the Data Validation list option, and they do not exist on the spreadsheet themselves to be selected as a range in the Data Validation list option.

Example: (this is simplified, I have about 40 country codes in this list)

Column A header in Row 1 is Country Code.
Rows 2-10 have a list of: USA,AUS,CAN,GBR,PRI .... etc.

What I need to do when any of the below applies:

1. If any option from the list is not selected the cell turns red.
2. Case sensitive. Must be all caps, so if they paste "usa", instead of "USA" the cell becomes red so they know what they did is invalid.
3. Ensure that if no data is in column B in the same row, that column A can be blank (for this I generally use =A2=""  highlight the needed range, and format no fill no boarder etc. If that needs to changed based on any possible formulas for the other requirements, please let me know.)

I have figured out the formula for these requirements if I use a list range of the data on another tab. =MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10),1)

But, are there formulas that I can use to do this with the existing Data Validation lists without having to re-create the lists on another tab of the spreadsheet?

Or, is creating the lists on another tab the only way to accomplish this?

Comment: With data validation they should be able to use a drop down if you have it selected which seems like it would serve as a solution for this problem of users not respecting the case sensitivity or misspelling something. Surely I'm missing information that makes this not viable?

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1 can be solved with Conditional Formatting. New rule, format only cells that contain, Format only cells with: Blanks, set format fill to red.

OR

Issue 1 and 2 can be solved with Data validation, Allow: List, Source = $A$2:$A$41 (or the correct location if you move the selections to a new tab). This way their only option is to select valid choices.

I'm not sure what you are asking for with issue 3

Comment: Yeah I was afraid creating the lists on a new tab was the only way to accomplish it. Thanks!

Comment: You can password protect the tab and hide it if you're concerned with anyone modifying it.